# SQL Server String split using cross apply returning an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using the following in a select statement to split a string on a ; delimiter
The query errors when there is actually no data in the field or no delimiter, how can I do error control here

```
select ParsedData.* 
from Table1
cross apply ( select str = field + ';;' ) f1
cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( ';', str ) ) ap1
cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( ';', str, p1 + 1 ) ) ap2
cross apply ( select p3 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p2 + 1 )) ap3
cross apply ( select p4 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p3 + 1 )) ap4
cross apply ( select p5 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p4 + 1 )) ap5
cross apply ( select p6 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p5 + 1 )) ap6
cross apply ( select A = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )         
                    ,B = substring( str, p1+1, p2-p1-1 )
                    ,C = SUBSTRING( str, p2+1 , p3-p2-1)
                    ,D = SUBSTRING( str, p3+1 , p4-p3-1)
                    ,E = SUBSTRING( str, p4+1 , p5-p4-1)
                    ,F = SUBSTRING( str, p5+1 , p6-p5-1)
          ) ParsedData
```

Error returned - Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Input
Full string
apple;mango;cherry;jam;cake

Output
A   B   C   D   E

apple   mango   cherry  jam cake

Thanks

Comment: why not change the `f1` block to `( select str = field + ';;;;;' ) f1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a where clause to exclude this data. However depending in the query plan, the expressions might be evaluated anyway (before the where is applied)

```
select ParsedData.* 
from Table1
cross apply ( select str = field + ';;' ) f1
cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( ';', str ) ) ap1
cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( ';', str, p1 + 1 ) ) ap2
cross apply ( select p3 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p2 + 1 )) ap3
cross apply ( select p4 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p3 + 1 )) ap4
cross apply ( select p5 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p4 + 1 )) ap5
cross apply ( select p6 = CHARINDEX(';', str, p5 + 1 )) ap6
cross apply ( select A = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )         
                    ,B = substring( str, p1+1, p2-p1-1 )
                    ,C = SUBSTRING( str, p2+1 , p3-p2-1)
                    ,D = SUBSTRING( str, p3+1 , p4-p3-1)
                    ,E = SUBSTRING( str, p4+1 , p5-p4-1)
                    ,F = SUBSTRING( str, p5+1 , p6-p5-1)
          ) ParsedData
 where str like '%;%;%;%;%'
```

However keep in mind that in SQL 2016 you can use `string_split` to do this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Using string_split returns 5 different rows of data, however i need one big string split to 5 columns.

Comment: OK so some sample input and output data would have helped here. Is it  fixed at 5 columns or can it be variable?

Comment: If input is one column 'apple;mango;cherry;Q2;35kgs' Output is 'apple mango cherry Q2 35kgs' split by delimiter ;

Comment: Yes I know that now. Can a single column ever have more than four `;`?

Comment: No, it will always have 4.

Comment: ..except when it has none (when your query errors?). So it can have zero or four right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173729/discussion-between-sth3-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: I've edited my answer slightly - it only processes rows with four `;`. But I think @squirrel has a better idea